# retain a value after running the program once?

Tags: java, binaryfiles, filereader, random-access

I'm making a program where I store a songs' title, artist, and genre into into a data file. Like this:

```
    public void writeSong(Song t) throws IOException {
    File myFile = new File(Song.getFileInput());
    RandomAccessFile write = new RandomAccessFile(myFile,"rw");
    write.writeChars(title);
    write.writeChars(artist);
    write.writeChars(genre);
    write.close();
}
```

After I do that, I'm supposed to read the data file and display the contents of it like this:

```
    public Song readSong() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    File myFile = new File(Song.getFileInput());
    RandomAccessFile read = new RandomAccessFile(myFile, "rw");
    String readTitle = null, readArtist = null, readGenre = null;
    Song so = null;

    read.seek(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < title.length(); i++){
        readTitle += read.readChar();
    }

    read.seek(50);
    for(int i = 0; i < artist.length(); i++){
        readArtist += read.readChar();
    }

    read.seek(100);
    for(int i = 0; i < genre.length(); i++){
        readGenre += read.readChar();
    }

    so = new Song(readTitle, readArtist, readGenre);
    read.close();
    return so;
}
```

If I assign it to a file called "songs.dat", it's supposed to write and read the songs off that file. After I exit the program and run it again, I make the file called "songs.dat" again. But when I want to read and display the songs, nothing happens. Does anyone how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`RandomAccessFile.seek(long position)` set the file position where you want to read or write.

When you begin to read your file you set the position to 0 with `read.seek(0)`. But from there you dont need to reset it :

```
public Song readSong() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    File myFile = new File(Song.getFileInput());
    RandomAccessFile read = new RandomAccessFile(myFile, "rw");
    String readTitle = "", readArtist = "", readGenre = "";
    Song so = null;

    read.seek(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < title.length(); i++){
        readTitle += read.readChar();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < artist.length(); i++){
        readArtist += read.readChar();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < genre.length(); i++){
        readGenre += read.readChar();
    }

    so = new Song(readTitle, readArtist, readGenre);
    read.close();
    return so;
}
```

I also initialize your String to empty String so you dont have "null" string in the first place as a result

Comment: That still didn't solve the problem. I still get the same output.

Comment: if you are sure that you are going through your readSong() and writeSong() function and that Song.getFileInput() is correct. Check that the user that launch your program has Read/Write permission on this file (or the directory where you actually create it)